# How to fix missing ul tags in html list snippet with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-lists

If I have a snippet of html like this:

```
<p><br><p>
<li>stuff</li>
<li>stuff</li>
```

Is there a way to clean this and add the missing ul/ol tags using [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), or another python library?

I tried `soup.prettify()` but it left as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's a built-in method which wraps groups of `li` elements into an `ul`. However, you can simply loop over the `li` elements, identify the first element of each `li` group and wrap it in `ul` tags. The next elements in the group are appended to the previously created `ul`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

ulgroup = 0
uls = []
for li in soup.findAll('li'):
        previous_element = li.findPrevious()
        # if <li> already wrapped in <ul>, do nothing
        if previous_element and previous_element.name == 'ul': 
            continue 
        # if <li> is the first element of a <li> group, wrap it in a new <ul>
        if not previous_element or previous_element.name != 'li':
            ulgroup += 1
            ul = soup.new_tag("ul")
            li.wrap(ul)
            uls.append(ul)
        # append rest of <li> group to previously created <ul>
        elif ulgroup > 0:
            uls[ulgroup-1].append(li)

print(soup.prettify())
```

For example, the following input:

```
html = '''
<p><br><p>
<li>stuff1</li>
<li>stuff2</li>
<div></div>
<li>stuff3</li>
<li>stuff4</li>
<li>stuff5</li>
'''
```

outputs:

```
<p>
 <br/>
 <p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    stuff1
   </li>
   <li>
    stuff2
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
  </div>
  <ul>
   <li>
    stuff3
   </li>
   <li>
    stuff4
   </li>
   <li>
    stuff5
   </li>
  </ul>
 </p>
</p>
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55619920-fixing-uls

Comment: This throws an error if the first element is an `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide which parser you are going to use. Different parsers treat malformed html *[differently](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)*.

The following BeautifulSoup methods will help you accomplish what you require

- *[new_tag()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag)* - create a new `ul` tag
- *[append()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append)*  - To append the newly created ul tag somewhere in the soup tree.
- *[extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)* - To extract the `li` tags one by one (which we can append to the `ul` tag)
- *[decompose()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose)* - To remove any unwanted tags from the tree. Which may be formed as a result of the parser's interpretation of the malformed html.

My Solution

Let's create a soup object using `html5lib` parser and see what we get

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<p><br><p>
<li>stuff</li>
<li>stuff</li>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
print(soup)
```

Outputs:

```
<html><head></head><body><p><br/></p><p>
</p><li>stuff</li>
<li>stuff</li>
</body></html>
```

The next step may vary according to what you want to accomplish. I want to remove the second empty p. Add a new `ul` tag and get all the `li` tags inside it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<p><br><p>
<li>stuff</li>
<li>stuff</li>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
second_p=soup.find_all('p')[1]
second_p.decompose()
ul_tag=soup.new_tag('ul')
soup.find('body').append(ul_tag)
for li_tag in soup.find_all('li'):
    ul_tag.append(li_tag.extract())
print(soup.prettify())
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   <br/>
  </p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    stuff
   </li>
   <li>
    stuff
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```